# Can telnet be used with any application level text protocol based on TCP/IP?

Tags: networking, http, tcpip, telnet

Can telnet be used with any application level text protocol like http or smtp?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It can be used with most, and you won't have much issue with common protocols like HTTP or SMTP, but Telnet is a protocol in itself and it does react to a few special characters.

From the Telnet wikipedia article:

> All data octets except 0xff are transmitted over the TCP transport as
> is. Therefore, a Telnet client application may also be used to
> establish an interactive raw TCP session, and it is commonly believed
> that such session which does not use the IAC (0xff, or 255 in decimal)
> is functionally identical.[citation needed]
>
> This is not the case, however, because there are other network virtual
> terminal (NVT) rules, such as the requirement for a bare carriage
> return character (CR, ASCII 13) to be followed by a NUL (ASCII 0)
> character, that distinguish the telnet protocol from raw TCP sessions.
> [clarification needed]
>
> On the other hand, many systems now possess true raw TCP
> clients, such as netcat or socat on UNIX and PuTTY on Windows, which
> also can be used to manually "talk" to other services without
> specialized client software. Nevertheless, Telnet is still sometimes
> used in debugging network services such as SMTP, IRC, HTTP, FTP or
> POP3 servers, to issue commands to a server and examine the responses,
> but of all these protocols only FTP really uses Telnet data format.
>
> Another difference of Telnet from a raw TCP session is that Telnet is
> not 8-bit clean by default. 8-bit mode may be negotiated, but
> high-bit-set octets may be garbled until this mode was requested, and
> it obviously will not be requested in non-Telnet connection. The 8-bit
> mode (so named binary option) is intended to transmit binary data, not
> characters though. The standard suggests the interpretation of codes
> 0000–0176 as ASCII, but does not offer any meaning for high-bit-set
> data octets. There was an attempt to introduce a switchable character
> encoding support like HTTP has,[3] but nothing is known about its
> actual software support.

As that mentions, `nc` or `socat` is a better tool (and `nc` lets you talk UDP via the command line), even though most of the time with HTTP and such you can get away with using telnet just fine.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, absolutely. And it's a great testing tool as well.

this is an example of how to do it using http.

http://www.esqsoft.com/examples/troubleshooting-http-using-telnet.htm

The older protocols on the internet tend to use text to communicate back and forth. This includes FTP and SMTP...

The exception to this rule is anything that is encrypted, so SSH and SSL are out.